# Cocoa Touch - Web View

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, webview

I need help with my WebView...I put this code in my `viewDidLoad` and it just crashes. Any advice?

```
[[gamerScoreWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with

```
[gamerScoreWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Also make sure that gamerScoreWebView is not nil by the time you do that.